# jQuery - simulate a page view counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I'm simulating a 8 digits counter with images, based on real numbers.

- Start date: October 1st
- Last Date: October 31st
- Number increase by days:  100 000 (DAYS)
- Number increase by hours:  10 000 (HOURS)
- Number increase by minutes: 1 000 (MIN)

Let's say a user open the page on October 5th, 3:10AM

The math should be something like: (DAY)*5 + (HOURS)*3 + (MIN)*10. Then display this number with the images (9 separates image).

The second part, to make it a bit more dynamic, if the user stay on the page and watch the counter, I want the numbers to animate from top to bottom to make a digital clock effect.

I want it to update  in a random way, not within a fixed interval. So let's say it can change in a delay of 10 sec to 1 minute.

I'm stuggling on where/how to start on this. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

For clearer reference, I want something like this: 
http://demos.2lessons.info/flip-visitor-counter/

Comment: What have you tried. This is not a code mill. Can you get the Date parts? Can you do the basic calculation?

Comment: Why don't you start by visiting the link you posted. Try to reverse engineer it and modify it to do what you want. That's how you learn how to do things. Grab the JS, CSS and Image Files and go to town.

Comment: So why don't you use [that flip counter](http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/) you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples: http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/

[Javascript source code](http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/demo/js/jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js)